# Need a guidance to choose best approach for dynamic web browsing with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I am working at the company and one of my tasks is to scan certain tender portals for relevant opportunities and share it with distribution lists I have in excel. It is not difficult but rather exhausting task, especially with other 100 things they put on me. So I decided to apply python to solve my pain, and provide opportunities for gains. I started with simple scraping with soup but I realized that I need something better, like bot or smart selenium based code. 
Problem : manual search and collections of info from websites ( search, click, download files, send them)
Sub problem for automated site scraping - credentials
Code background - rare learns from different platforms based on problem at hand ( mostly boring ), mostly python and data science related courses

Desired help - suggest way, framework, examples, for automated web browsing using python so I can collect all info in the matter of clicks ( Data collection using excel is basic, do not have access to databases, however, more sophisticated ideas are appreciated)

PS. Working two jobs and trying to support my family while searching for other career options, but my dedicated and care for business eat up my time as I do not want to be a trouble maker, thus while trying to push to management (which is old school) for support, time goes by.

Please and thank you in advance for your mega smart advices! Many thanks

Comment: This is a major undertaking. If I understand you correctly, as you're working with MS Excel, you might want to see what is possible constructing code there with Visual Basic for Excel as then your data will be converted into the format you want. Otherwise, check out the O'Reilly publisher's book 'Web Scraping with Python, 2nd Edition'. In any case, be prepared to spend a fair amount of time before seeing any results. Answer below is a good start. AND notice that the tag `[web-scraping]` shows ~24000 Q/A. Try searching for your particular issues earlier, than later. Good luck!

Comment: @Greg I added an example per your edit.

Answer (score 3):

BeautifulSoup not going to be up to the job simply because it is a parser, not a web browser.

[MechanicalSoup](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html) might be an option for you of the sites are not too complex and do not require Javascript execution to function.

[Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) is essentially a robotic version of your favourite web browser.

Whether I choose Selenium or MechanicalSoup depends on whether my target data requires Javascript execution, either during login or to get the data itself.

**Let's go over your requirements:**

- **Search:** Can the search be conducted through a get request? I.e. is the search done based on variables in the URL? Google something and then look at the URL of that Google Search. Is there something similar on your target websites? If yes, MechanicalSoup. If not, Selenium.
- **Click:** As far as I know, MechanicalSoup cannot explicitly click. It can follow URLs if it is given what to look for (and usually this is good enough), but it cannot click a button. Selenium is needed for this.
- **Download:** Either of them can do this as long as no button clicking is required. Again, can it just follow the path of where the button leads to?
- **Send:** Outside the scope of both. You need to look at something else for this, although plenty of mail libraries exist.
- **Credentials:** Both can do this, so the key question is whether login is dependent on Javascript.

This really hinges on the specific details of what you seek to do.

**EDIT: Here is an example of what I have done with MechanicalSoup:**
https://github.com/MattGaiser/mindsumo-scraper

It is a program which logs into a website, is pointed to a specific page, scrapes that page as well as the other relevant pages to which it links, and from those scrapings generates a CSV of the challenges I have won, the score I earned, and the link to the image of the challenge (which often has insights).